# MySQL Max Field Size - Get Status

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing some pretty huge and dynamic arrays in a LONGTEXT field by serializing them. I'm worried that we'll quite soon hit the limit of storage for a single field (4GB). I have created another column to store data in for users once the first one is nearly full.

Is there a way to check a field's contents for how much of the space has been used and then I can use that to decide on whether to put more data in that column or the next column? Is the simplest way to pull out the string and count the characters and divide by 2^32-1? Is that the quickest way?

Thanks.

Comment: You know that the size limit is meant for one row in that column, right? Not for the whole column. Just curious, what are you storing there?

Comment: Hi, I think I know. I think each field in a row can have upto 4gb in it if it is a longtext. But I am going to run over that limit. So need a way to switch to a new column so the field in that row in that column doesn't overflow.

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself if it's really necessary to store it in a database. Maybe you should rather store a link to a file. I'm still wondering why and what someone stores in a DB that is that large.